# Referencing stream.Position dramatically increase execution time

Tags: c#, io

Any idea why referencing the Position property of a stream dratically increases IO time ?

The execution time of:

```
        sw.Restart();
        fs = new FileStream("tmp", FileMode.Open);
        var br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            fs.Position+=0; //Should be a NOOP
            a[i] = br.ReadDouble();
        }
        Debug.Write("\n");
        Debug.Write(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());
        Debug.Write("\n");
        fs.Close();
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.Write(a[0].ToString() + "\n");
        Debug.Write(a[n - 1].ToString() + "\n");
```

is ~100 times slower than the equivalent loop without the "fs.Position+=0;".
Normally the intention with using Seek (or manipulating the Position property) is to speed up things when you dont need all data in the file.
But if, e.g., you only need every second value in the file, it is aparently much faster to read the entire file and discard the data that you dont need, than to skip every second value in the file by moving Stream.Position

Comment: *why* should that be a "noop"?  At worst it re-assignes the same value--which *does* have consequences.

Comment: Setting `Position` causes `Seek` to get called.

Answer (score 4):

You're doing two things:

- Fetching the position
- Setting it

It's entirely possible that *each* of those performs a direct interaction with the underlying Win32 APIs, whereas normally you can read a fair amount of data without having to interop with native code at all, due to buffering.

I'm slightly surprised at the extent to which it's worse, but I'm not surprised that it *is* worse. I think it would be worth you doing separate tests to find out which has more effect - the read or the write. So write similar code which either *just* reads or *just* writes. Note that that should affect the code you write later, but it may satisfy your curiosity a bit further.

You might also try

```
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
```

... which is more likely to be ignored as a genuine no-op. But even so, skipping a single byte using `fs.Seek(1, SeekOrigin.Current)` may well be expensive again.

Comment: No to mention the distinct possibility that the Position *changed* between when the value was retrieved and the addition of 0--which means it actually seeks to a different part of the file.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: Indeed, yes.

Answer (score 1):

From the reflector:

```
public override long Position {
  [SecuritySafeCritical]
  get {
    if (this._handle.IsClosed) {
      __Error.FileNotOpen();
    }
    if (!this.CanSeek) {
      __Error.SeekNotSupported();
    }
    if (this._exposedHandle) {
      this.VerifyOSHandlePosition();
    }
    return this._pos + (long)(this._readPos - this._readLen + this._writePos);
  }
  set {
    if (value < 0L) {
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NeedNonNegNum"));
    }
    if (this._writePos > 0) {
      this.FlushWrite(false);
    }
    this._readPos = 0;
    this._readLen = 0;
    this.Seek(value, SeekOrigin.Begin);
  }
}
```

(self explanatory) - essentially every set causes flush and there is no check if you're setting the same value to the position; if you're not happy with the FileStream, make your own stream proxy that would handle position update more gracefully :)